# Can an SVM be trained on multivalued features?

Tags: classification, svm

I cant wrap my head around a fact that how can I use multivalued features to train a classifier let's say SVM. For an example, lets say I have four features to look at, each of those features have 4 values under them. Can I use these numbers to train a classifier or I have to have only one values per features?

Comment: Do you mean multivalued labels?

Comment: If you have 4 features, each having four values, can't you transform them to 16 features?

Comment: Please give us more details. How do you have four values per feature? Are these multiple measurements?

Answer (score 2):

If your features are all numeric, then you can use them as is. If they are categories, you can create dummy variables for each feature.

Comment: Adding to Arun's answer, using K-1 dummy variables (where K is the number of categories) is the way this is usually done.